# Pointers and the ways of de-referencing it

Tags: c, pointers

I have a doubt in de-referencing the pointers
I wrote a simple code but i dont know the reason why it is failing in certain condition can someone pls tell what is the reason for it to fail. and if we have char  `*ptr = "stack overflow"` then the compiler itself will allocate memory to it.

```
int main()
{
   int *ptr = 10;
   double *dptr = 111.111
   printf("%d", *ptr); //will give segmentation violation as we are trying to access the content in location 10
   printf("%d", ptr);//o/p will be 10 
   printf("%lf", dptr); // will give segmentation violation 
   printf("%lf", *dptr); // will give segmentation violation

}
```

Comment: You should be getting compiler warnings like it's your birthday.

Comment: Please read about pointers, there is enough online material on that. You are completely off the track.

Comment: Throw away your compiler - I think you're using TurboC

Comment: This code can't even compile, there's a semicolon missing!

Comment: Ah, @AlexeyFrunze I was just thinking about your other answer -

Comment: @Aniket That other q/a isn't very relevant here. This code doesn't compile and, when made to compile, exhibit multiple undefined behaviors and, perhaps, some implementation-specific behaviors as well.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze well I just wanted to post a theory of what pointers really are.. OP does not seem to understand what pointers are.

Comment: @Aniket Oh, I see. But that answer wasn't really intended to explain their function and proper use, it only warns that they aren't necessarily implemented under-the-hood as one might be expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *ptr = 10;
double *dptr = 111.111
```

The problem lie in the above two lines.

`ptr` points to the address `10` and `dptr` is I don't know where it is pointing.

Dereferencing these pointers will certainly yield undefined behavior.. usually a segmentation violation fault.

Fix:

```
int main(){
   int iVal = 10; 
   double dVal = 111.11;

   int *ptr = &iVal;
   double *dptr = &dval;

   printf("%d", *ptr); // ok
   printf("%p", (void *)ptr);// ok
   printf("%p", (void *)dptr); // ok
   printf("%lf", *dptr); // ok
   return 0;
}
```

---

Theory: A pointer is a variable that holds address - or as Alexey Frunze says:

> The C standard does not define what a pointer is internally and how it
>   works internally. This is intentional so as not to limit the number of
>   platforms, where C can be implemented as a compiled or interpreted
>   language.
>
> A pointer value can be some kind of ID or handle or a combination of
>   several IDs (say hello to x86 segments and offsets) and not
>   necessarily a real memory address. This ID could be anything, even a
>   fixed-size text string. Non-address representations may be especially
>   useful for a C interpreter.

Comment: One should note that `%p` is defined for `void *` only. So one ought to cast accordingly: `printf("%p", (void *) ptr)` This btw is one of the few cases where casting in C is a must.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Alk - corrected the code

Comment: You are welcome. And lucky us, we are not talking about printing values of function pointers here, as this would bring us into serious trouble ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
int *ptr = 10;
```

you tell the compiler that `ptr` is a pointer to the *address* 10. Dereferencing this address will cause *undefined behavior* and may cause a crash.

You would most likely want something like:

```
int ival = 10;
int *ptr = &ival;
```

Similar for the `double` pointer.

Comment: where is dptr pointing to?

Comment: @Aniket That is a good question. Either `111` or whatever `111.111` corresponds to. I don't think it's specified what the compiler should do in this case.

Comment: so that seems like undefined behavior - even probably an error!

Comment: Here i am assigning values directly and checking how the compiler behaves, if it fails i want to know the reason for its failure

Comment: @user1985641 No, you're **not** assigning values directly. A pointer variable is a variable whose value is the _address_ of where it points to. Assigning a value to a pointer variable sets the _address_ not the value it should point to. You also can not point directly to literal values, as these are not stored in memory and therefore have no address that can be pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

char *ptr = "stack overflow"

```
  This buffer was allocated in TEXT SEGMENT hence there is no issue of dereferencing and getting the address but if you modify the data content its a voilation [Segmentation Fault]
```

Note:-
Please refer from online,how many segments will be created for a program (process) ?
[Generally, Heap Segment,Stack Segment,Data Segment & Text Segment]

Answer (score 0):

The reason `char *ptr = "stack overflow"` works and `int *ptr = 10` does not is that `10` is just the number 10, but `"stack overflow"` evaluates to a pointer to the characters.

String literals are special kinds of constants. The compiler puts the characters of the string somewhere in memory, and the value of the string literal is a pointer to those characters. Conversely, integer and floating-point constants are just their values; they are not pointers.